# Is there a way to make Phing ZipTask output a file that can be extracted with a 1.0 version of zip?

Tags: php, wordpress, zip, phing

We use [Phing](https://www.phing.info) on a macOS High Sierra to deploy a WordPress plugin and its [ZipTask](https://www.phing.info/docs/stable/hlhtml/index.html#ZipTask) to build the final archive.

The output of file command against the archives give us this information:

```
push-notifications-for-wordpress.zip: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

From which we can see the minimum version to extract archive is v2.0.

Now, we are having troubles with WordPress installer system that does not support those archives:

```
Could not extract file from archive. push-notifications-for-wordpress/./
```

If we extract the file and re-create it with the zip command line resulting in a v1.0 compatible file:

```
push-notifications-for-wordpress.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

WordPress will successfully extract it and we are reasonably sure that minimum version needed to extract file is the key problem.

So, *is there a way to force ZipTask to make a v1.0 compliant zip archive?*

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With version 2.0, the Zip specification introduced support for *folders*. Previously it did not:

```
   4.4.3 version needed to extract (2 bytes)
        4.4.3.2 Current minimum feature versions are as defined below:

         2.0 - File is a folder (directory)
         2.0 - File is compressed using Deflate compression
         2.0 - File is encrypted using traditional PKWARE encryption
```

Source: https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT

So it does not make sense to support zip v1 at all, and you have to look for the error elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. As WordPress seems to not support version v2 at all, we need to fallback to v1 in order to make plugins compatible. This is the reason we cannot use the newer version and we are asking a way to force ZipTask to make a v1.0 compliant zip archive.